# Linear independencies with space vectors

Tags: vectors

Hi I've been getting ready for my finals and I am not quite sure if I answered the questions right. Can I have your opinions on it please?

Exercise:
a-) Is it true that two vectors of R3 are necessarily linearly independent?

b) Is it possible to express the vector u =(1 1 1) as a combination of the vectors v = (1 1 0) and w = ( 1 0 1)?

What I've done 
a) Two space  vectors are linearly independent if and only if the combination of xu+yv = 0 with x=0 and y = 0. The assertion is false.

b/ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc4OO.jpg)

I concluded that the vector u cannot be expressed by the vectors v and w.

Answer (score 0):

A) the vectors (1,0,0) , (2,0,0) are linearly dependent vectors in R^3.
B) Hint: Set up a system of equations.

Comment: So does it that my answer to a) is correct?

Comment: It's incomplete

Comment: All you need is a counter example. You can have 2 linearly independent vectors in R^3. So a counterexample suffices.